# Tkinter scrollbar not scrollable

Tags: python, tkinter

I followed some tutorial on attaching a scrollbar to a textbox. However, in the tutorial, the scrollbar is really a "bar". When I tried myself, I can only press the arrows to move up or down, the middle part is not movable. May I know what I did wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
message = tk.Text(root, yscrollcommand = scroll.set, height = 25, width = 60)
message.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
for i in range(50):
    message.insert(tk.END, f'This is line {i}\n')
scroll.config(command = message.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Tk window generated by the code]

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047206/stretch-scrollbar-to-canvas-size-in-tkinter

Comment: ***"in the tutorial, the scrollbar is really a "bar""***: Change to `scroll.grid(.., sticky='ns')`

Comment: Also there is a `ScrolledText` available which is basically a `Text` widget with a built-in scrollbar. `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `sticky='nsew'` to `Scrollbar` widget.

`sticky='nsew'` will make the `Scrollbar` widget to expand to fill up the entire cell (at grid position `row=0` & `column=1`) at every side (n-*north*, s-*south*, e-*east*, w-*west*)

Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root)

# add sticky option to the Scrollbar widget
scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky='nsew')

message = tk.Text(root, yscrollcommand = scroll.set, height = 25, width = 60)
message.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
for i in range(50):
    message.insert(tk.END, f'This is line {i}\n')
scroll.config(command = message.yview)

root.mainloop()
```