# TKINTER: create_window()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a short question: What does the `create_window()` function for a `Canvas` do? Oh, and does this function have something to do with setting a `Scrollbar` inside a `Canvas`?

Comment: take a look at this: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html

Comment: then at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727804/python-and-tkinter-using-scrollbars-on-a-canvas   and next time try to find the answer without posting a new question first, this took one google search to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_window` creates an object on the canvas based off of a widget. For example, you could create a button widget, and use `create_window` to embed that button in the canvas.

This has nothing to do with "setting a `Scrollbar` inside a `Canvas`". However, it is often used to make it a scrollable frame. For normal canvases, though, you don't need to use `create_window` in order to tie a scrollbar to a canvas.