# Python tkinter unable to add scrollbar to figure embedded in canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am working on a program that 1) Opens images in a folder 2) Complies all those images into a figure 3) inserts the figure into the canvas. My original issue was that in the complied figure, all the pictures were too small to see. So, I wanted to display one picture/section of the figure at a time and scroll down to the next one.

My current issue is that I am unable to insert a scrollbar into the figure/canvas. The error I get is:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas)

AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I read that scrollbars can only be added to frames, but when I try to add a frame to the canvas I get the same error. My code is as follows:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk
except:
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *

import tkMessageBox
import os

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

class Project(tk.Tk):

    #Base line code to initialize everything 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Project")

        container = tk.Frame(self) #Define frame/edge of window
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) #fill will fill space you have allotted pack. Expand will take up all white space.
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) #0 sets minimum size weight sets priority

        self.frames = {}

        for F in [StartPage]:
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame 
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") 

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() #raise to front


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Figure Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        #add subplot with all images in folder 'PictureFolder'
        f = Figure(figsize = (8,8), dpi=100)#define figure      
        i=1
        for picture in  os.listdir("/home/pi/Desktop/PictureFolder/"):
            a = f.add_subplot(6,1,i) #add subplot RCP. Pth pos on grid with R rows and C columns
            img = mpimg.imread("/home/pi/Desktop/PictureFolder/" + picture) #read in image
            a.imshow(img) #Renders image
            i+=1

        #add canvas which is what we intend to render graph to and fill it with figure
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self) 
        #frame2 = tk.Frame(canvas)
        canvas.draw() #raise canvas
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X, expand=True) #Fill options: BOTH, X, Y Expand options:  

        #Add figure toolbar
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self) #add traditionalmatplotlib toolbar
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        #Add scrollbar
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas)
        scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand = YES, fill=BOTH)

        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)





app = Project()
app.geometry("640x480")
app.mainloop()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter: using scrollbars on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727804/tkinter-using-scrollbars-on-a-canvas)

Comment: There is a big problem with your imports. I bet this is part of your problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate Mike? If I comment out just the scrollbar section, the code works just fine with the same imports.

Comment: Well maybe the code works but your imports are overriding each other. This will cause problems down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All the `canvas` objects in the code need to be replaced with `canvas.get_tk_widget()`