# tkinter Scrollbar collapses the Canvas it's in

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm attempting to make a program with two sections. The left section will display a vertically scrollable list while the right section will display info based on the items selected in the list. Ignore the right section since I haven't gotten there yet.

Below is a general idea of what it'll look like except the left section will scroll vertically.

[image]

Unfortunately when I pack the scrollbar the left section completely disappears.

[image]

Below is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Tasks(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, builds=None):
        super().__init__()

        if builds is None:
            self.builds = []
        else:
            self.builds = builds

        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('1000x600')
        self.configure(bg='red')

        self.tasks_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, bg='green')
        self.tasks_frame = tk.Frame(self.tasks_canvas)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.tasks_canvas, orient='vertical',command=self.tasks_canvas.yview)

        self.canvas_frame = self.tasks_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.tasks_frame, anchor='n')

        self.tasks_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.tasks_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tasks()
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm sure I'm missing a simply concept but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of the way `pack` geometry manager works. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734187/8653690). Quoting it here:

> By default `pack` will attempt to shrink (or grow) a container to exactly fit its children. Because the scrollbar is a children of the canvas in the, **the canvas shrinks to fit**.

To get around this, you can use an extra `Frame` to contain the `Canvas` and the `Scrollbar` and set the parent of the Scrollbar as this Frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Tasks(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, builds=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('400x120')
        self.configure(bg='red')

        self.t_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.t_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.tasks_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.t_frame, width=100, bg='green')
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.t_frame, orient='vertical',command=self.tasks_canvas.yview)

        self.tasks_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.tasks_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tasks()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Result]